# Remotely Controlling Picture Slideshows From One Central Location to Thirty Remote Locations

Tags: slideshow, remote-connection

I work for a company that has 30 convenience store locations and we're looking to have display screens in all the stores that play the same content. We want to be able to remotely control the content from the home office (make changes, stop and start it, etc.).

I have looked into using roundabout solutions like GoToMyPC.com and GoToMeeting.com etc but I was wondering if anyone knows of any good software or internet services that can provide remotely controlling a slideshow of pictures for multiple locations.

Thanks. (Sorry if this isn't exactly the correct Stack Exchange site to post this question to, I figured I'd start here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to want a more commercial solution for this. While we try to stay away from recommending specific products here, the *type* of software you're looking for is called [*Digital Signage Software*](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+signage+software) and there are a number of setups available from small to very large scale.

Comment: Great, thank you, that's exactly what I needed (I didn't even know what it's actually called).